# React lifecycle method on createElement()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to store my components into an array to get further access to methods like `addChild`. I can't find a suitable lifecycle method to store the component. Right now I'm abusing the `getInitialState` function.

```
components = {};

function Component(){
  return React.createClass({
    getInitialState : function({
      components[this.props.id] = {addChild: this.addChild}; 
      return child : [];
    }),
    addChild(child){
      this.state.children.push(child);
      this.setState({
        children : this.state.children
      });

    ...
  });
}
```

This function triggers only if the component is rendered. Is there a lifecycle function that is executed after the creation of a component with `createElement()`?

Or is there a better way to store the component to get further access to methods?

Comment: I find unclear what you are trying to do. You can store the elements that are created I do not see where is the issue with this. You can also access their properties. What you cannot do, however, is modifying them as they will be read only. You cannot either access their state as only the instances will have one, not the element. If you need to access the instances, you can use [`ref`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html).

Comment: Methods like `addChild` look like an anti-pattern. Why don't you just re-render the elements when a new child show up? This is the use react has be designed for.

Comment: After reading more carefully, it looks like what you want is ref.

Comment: I like to save the instances into an object to dynamically add children to existing elements via an id. Like `components["id"].addChild(new Button());` for example. The component shall rerender itself after adding the new child.

Comment: I understood. I cannot think of any case where it would be a good idea with React. I may be wrong. But usually you just change the properties from the parent component and let react do its magic.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the instance of an element once it is rendered by providing a callback to the [`ref` property](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) of this element.

Here is how you could use it (I assumed you have a JSX *and ES6* transpiler):

```
var instances = {};
const storeInstance = (i) => instances[i.props.id] = i;

var foo1 = (<Hello id="foo1" ref={storeInstance}/>);
var foo2 = (<Hello id="foo2" ref={storeInstance}/>);
var foo3 = (<Hello id="foo3" ref={storeInstance}/>);
```

[Here is a live version](https://jsfiddle.net/kzaa69du/).

However, I would advise caution with such method as it can very rapidly become an anti-pattern. It is usually easier and more elegant to use the bottom-up re-render React mechanism. You just update the element's property from its parent and let React do the rest.